# PHP: Check for profile fields completedness

Tags: php

I have a social networking site built on a PHP framework. I'm using a plugin to award members points when they update their profile. Right now, whenever a member clicks on 'Save' it triggers the profileupdate event, and that event triggers the points being awarded. But, even if the profile fields are all empty, the event is still triggered and they still get points… so, my clever users are gaming the system to get points without really updating their profile :\

I want to add a function that checks that the profile fields aren't empty -- or, ideally, checks that a significant amount of changes have been made to at least 1 of the profile fields, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm still pretty new to PHP (about 1 year experience), so if anyone could help both with explaining what the checking process should be and the specifics on the code to execute the checking function, I'd really appreciate it!

Here are the current events and functions:

When the owner of the page clicks on 'Save', this is the event in the core of the PHP framework that gets triggered to notify the user of the update:

```
$owner->save();
trigger_event('profileupdate', $owner->type, $owner);
system_message(echo("profile:saved"));
```

This is the function in the points plugin that checks to see if the plugin is configured to award points based on a profile update, and then calls the points_add function to add points to the user:

```
function points_profile($event, $type, $object) {
    if ($points = get_plugin_setting('profileupdate')) {
        if (function_exists('points_add')) {
            points_add(get_logged_in_user_guid(), $points, $event, $type, $object->entity_guid);
        }
    }
    return(true);
}
```

This is an example of how the individual profile fields are defined/labelled -- ie, "admin_defined_profile_1"

```
if (save_config("admin_defined_profile_$id", $label) &&
    save_config("admin_defined_profile_type_$id", $type) &&
    save_config('profile_custom_fields', $fieldlist))
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you mentioned WHAT framework you're using? If it's something custom, then there's no real way for us to know what all those function calls are doing.

Answer (score 0):

look on rowcount() http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

it will -on single UPDATE -return 1 if anything was actually changed and 0 if nothing was changed.

Comment: Great - thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about that. It looks like it might not work across all sql versions etc but I'm looking into if this'll work for this & will report back. Thanks.

Comment: So I've tried updating the function to check if the row count is 1 but this doesn't seem to have had any effect...?

function check_for_profile_change () {
 if ($stmt->rowCount()=1) {
    $function = $profile_updated;} else {echo "No changes were made to your profile"}
}
function add_points_profile ($event, $type, $object) {if ($points = get_plugin_setting('profileupdate')) {
if (function_exists('profile_updated')) {
if (function_exists('points_add')) {
userpoints_add(get_logged_in_user_guid(), $points, $event, $type, $object->entity_guid);}
}
}
return(true);
}